# Certificate not found error while using xConnect on Azure from Visual Studio Application

Tags: azure, xconnect, paas

I have created a Sitecore 9.0 PaaS in Azure. I am trying to work with xConnect by following this article - https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/getting-started/, tutorial 1.

The certificate I used to create our environment in Azure is installed locally and I have the thumbprint. I have replaced the thumbprint and the URLs in the code where requested. When I run my code.

I am getting:

> "The certificate was not found."

I have followed this article for troubleshooting, https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/10/All-about-xConnect-Security/, especially under the "The certificate was not found" section. However, I still can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is a security access to your local certificate store. Are you running Visual Studio as administrator? If you do that, does this resolve the issue? Lack of read access to the certificate would yield this error.

If this is not a security issue, then it may be a cert store configuration issue. In the tutorials, the configuration for the client is instantiated with a hard-coded certificate store connection string. Have you validated that this configuration matches for your system? If the path does not match to where your certificate is installed, even if the thumbprint matches the certificate will not be found.

Comment: Hi Jay.

I am running visual studio as an administrator.

To verify that the path of the certificate is correct, I used this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144141/can-i-list-locally-installed-digital-certificates-with-c, to validate the certificate and it's location. It is correct. The certificate exists when StoreName=My and StoreLocation=CurrentUser or LocalMachine.